# Overcoming "Error: unexpected input" in RCurl

Tags: r, rcurl

I am trying and failing to use RCurl to automate the process of fetching a spreadsheet from a web site, China Labour Bulletin's [Strike Map](http://strikemap.clb.org.hk/strikes/en).

Here is the URL for the spreadsheet with the options set as I'd like them:

http://strikemap.clb.org.hk/strikes/api.v4/export?FromYear=2011&FromMonth=1&ToYear=2015&ToMonth=6&_lang=en

Here is the code I'm using:

```
library(RCurl)
temp <- tempfile()
temp <- getForm("http://strikemap.clb.org.hk/strikes/api.v4/export",
  FromYear="2011", FromMonth="1", 
  ToYear="2015", ToMonth="6",
  _lang="en")
```

And here is the error message I get in response:

```
Error: unexpected input in:
"     ToYear=2015, ToMonth=6,
     _"
```

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: getForm("http://strikemap.clb.org.hk/strikes/api.v4/export",.params = list( ToYear="2015",ToMonth="6",FromYear="2011", FromMonth="1"))  this works but I don't know how and why I was not able to add _lang in the parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enclosing `_lang` with a backtick.

```
temp <- getForm("http://strikemap.clb.org.hk/strikes/api.v4/export",
                FromYear="2011",
                FromMonth="1",
                ToYear="2015",
                ToMonth="6",
                `_lang`="en")
```

I think R has trouble on the argument starting with an underscore. This seems to have worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was the underscore and didn't know how to escape it.

Of course, now I can't read the temp file into workable form. Here's what I'm trying:

`library(readxl)`
`CLB <- read_excel(temp)`

And here's what I'm getting:

`Error in file.exists(path) : invalid 'file' argument`

Any suggestions on that would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should ask another question for your new issue, rather than adding it in a comment.

Comment: I replied because I thought it might be a residual issue from the first process instead of a new one, but I appreciate your advice and will follow it. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. :) You'll get a better response with a new question and it's in line with how the site is designed to work - separate questions for separate issues. SO is all about asking good questions and getting good answers. If you ping me in the comment here I can always try and look at that one too.

Comment: Follow-up question finally posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220677/invalid-path-argument-with-xlconnect).