# Invalid 'path' argument with XLConnect

Tags: r, rcurl, xlconnect

I am trying and failing to get the following process to complete in R Version 3.1.2:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XLConnect)
yr <- substr(Sys.Date(), 1, 4)
mo <- as.character(as.numeric(substr(Sys.Date(), 6, 7)) - 1)
temp <- tempfile()
temp <- getForm("http://strikemap.clb.org.hk/strikes/api.v4/export",
  FromYear = "2011", FromMonth = "1", 
  ToYear = yr, ToMonth = mo,
  `_lang` = "en")
CLB <- readWorksheetFromFile(temp, sheet=1)
unlink(temp)
```

I have been able manually to export the requested data set and then read it into R from a local directory using the same readWorksheetFromFile syntax. My goal now is to do the whole thing in R. The call to the API seems to work ([thanks to some earlier help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643213/overcoming-error-unexpected-input-in-rcurl)), but the process fails at the next step, when I try to ingest the results. Here's what happens:

```
> CLB <- readWorksheetFromFile(temp, sheet=1)
Error in path.expand(filename) : invalid 'path' argument
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong or what's broken?

Comment: I did, and I get essentially the same error: `Error in file.exists(path) : invalid 'file' argument`.

Comment: I think you've mistakenly assumed that the result of `getForm()` is a file.

Comment: Ahhh, okay. What is it, HTML? If I run `str()` on the temp file produced by my `getForm()` call, I see that it's an atomic vector composed of unrecognizable elements. So how do I translate that vector in the table I'm after? Or is there a better way to get there?

Comment: You need to save the results of `getForm()` to a file...

Comment: Thank you! I've (almost) gotten this to work now. I will post the details in an answer and start a new question for the remaining glitch if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem didn't lie with XLConnect at all. Based on Hadley's tip that I needed to save the results of my query to the API to a file before reading them back into R, I have managed (almost) to complete the process using the following code:

```
library(httr)
library(readxl)
yr <- substr(Sys.Date(), 1, 4)
mo <- as.character(as.numeric(substr(Sys.Date(), 6, 7)) - 1)
baseURL <- paste0("http://strikemap.clb.org.hk/strikes/api.v4/export?FromYear=2011&FromMonth=1&ToYear=", yr, "&ToMonth=", mo, "&_lang=en")
queryList <- parse_url(baseURL)
clb <- GET(build_url(queryList), write_disk("clb.temp.xlsx", overwrite=TRUE))
CLB <- read_excel("clb.temp.xlsx")
```

The object that creates, CLB, includes the desired data with one glitch: the dates in the first column are not being read properly. If I open "clb.temp.xlsx" in Excel, they show up as expected (e.g., 2015-06-30, or 6/30/2015 if I click on the cell). But `read_excel()` is reading them as numbers that don't track to those dates in an obvious way (e.g., 42185 for 2015-06-30). I tried fixing that by specifying that they were dates in the call to read_excel, but that produced a long string of warnings about expecting dates but getting those numbers.

If I use `readWorkSheetFromFile()` instead of `read_excel` at that last step, here's what happens:

```
> CLB <- readWorksheetFromFile("clb.temp.xlsx")
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readWorksheet’ for signature ‘"workbook", "missing"’
```

I will search for a solution to the problem using read_excel and will create a new question if I can't find one.

Comment: I was able to convert the numbers to the proper dates in R using this line of code: `CLB$Date <- as.Date(CLB$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d", origin = "1899-12-30")`. I have no idea why that origin date works and had to figure it out through trial and error, but there it is.